STM32Cube IDE cmake target_compile_definitions not picked up by indexer
I have a Cmake project with in the cmakelists the following command
target_compile_definitions(${PROJECT_NAME}
    PRIVATE CORE_CM7
    PRIVATE STM32H755xx
)

The projects compiles perfectly however in the editor it shows #if defined(CORE_CM7) as inactive piece of code.
I cannot seem to get the Indexer to recognize these definitions.
I have even thought of dirty solution as in exporting it to a header and including that everywhere.
But it kinda defeats the purpose in the first place.
